# How to debug in Liferay 7?

Tags: debugging, liferay, liferay-7.3

I'm using Liferay Developer Studio 3.8 and Liferay Portal Tomcat 7.3.1.

I would like to know how can I debug Liferay code, given that the usual Eclipse option as "Watch" or "Inspect" are disabled even starting the server in "Debug mode"?

Also, I cannot use the "Variables" perspective or the "Debug Shell".

[Options disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzkQ.png)

[Variables disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsggC.png)

Does somebody know a dummy manual to debug in Liferay?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The line suggested by Purvesh is already inserted in setenv file.

Following the steps provided by Andre, I still cannot add variables or insert expressions in debug shell. And also, nothing happens with the breakpoints at lines 68 and 69.
[Remote debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6dgL.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can start your server with `catalina.sh jpda start` (guess this should works with .bat too). In eclipse run „Remote Application“ Debug. Your debug Port should be 8000 (per default).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Below line in your setenv.bat/setenv.sh file.

> CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

2. Restart tomcat server.
3. Set debug configuration and put breakpoints.
4. Run your application.